# get the bbox of a padding in numpy, without creating the padded array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, padding

I have a numpy array (can assume 2d):

```
a = np.zeros((w_world, h_world))
```

and a box given as ltwh relative to that array [can be out of bounds]

```
b = np.zeros((w_box, h_box))
```

I would like to find where `b` would lie in `a` if I padded it [like so](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html).

---

I can obviously implement this function [many modes], but I am looking for some built in that already does this.

Comment: What you expected is unclear, would you provide a small example? Do you just want to add the padding to the coordinates?

Comment: When you pad a box ltwh in the world coordinates of some other box ltwh, you get a new ltwh which represent the location of the padded box in that same world. I am looking to get these new coordinates, which should correspond to at least some of the modes in np.pad

Comment: I see what you mean, then AFAIK you would have to implement your own function